# How to use clip method in jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I want to set lines inside to clipping region using jsPDF like below.

[image]

So, I called methods like blew.
I Called .clip() after calling .lines() with a style argument of null like below.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.lines([[50, 0], [0, 50], [-50, 0], [0, -50]], 20, 20, [1.0, 1.0], null, true); // horizontal line
doc.clip();
doc.rect(50, 50, 100, 100, 'F');
```

I succeeded clipping lines!

But I cannot make clip regions more than one.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They actually fixed this one recently but apparently didn’t want to break the existing API, so they added a new method by the name `clip_fixed`:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/commit/e32f0a2b222a940b0f228457371a118fc138ec28#diff-8162ee9f6251a2016741ffe67239c3c4

Once you have drawn your clip path with a style object of null and called `doc.clip_fixed()`, all shapes you draw subsequently will be clipped to your current clip path.

If afterwards you ever need to draw another shape **without the clipping** applied, you’ll realize that there is nothing like *doc.unclip()*. So your best option to draw unclipped shapes later on is to first save your current state to the Graphics State Stack before drawing your clip path, and when you’re done drawing your last clipped shape, restore the previous state from the stack. Unfortunately the API to this stack is not yet exposed via jsPDF, but you can get access to jsPDF’s internal command queue via `doc.internal.write()` to insert any PDF command that is not handled by jsPDF.

So to create a reversable clipping you do:

```
doc.internal.write('q'); // saves the currrent state
// any draw command with a style value of null
doc.clip_fixed();
// any number of draw commands with strokes, fills, or null for compound paths
doc.internal.write('Q'); // restores the state to where there was no clipping
```

Further reading on clipping:
http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0234.htm

Answer (score 2):

Used several hours to get this to work. Here is an update for **jsPDf version 2.5.1**.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.lines([[50, 0], [0, 50], [-50, 0], [0, -50]], 20, 20, [1.0, 1.0], null, true); // horizontal line
doc.clip();
doc.discardPath();
doc.rect(50, 50, 100, 100, 'F');
```